# Redirecting codeigniter project to https with htaccess: never complete

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a Codeigniter 3 site from http to https.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I get this error:

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: No that's my entire `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Your rules look like they should work, did you try clearing your browsers cache?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried in other browsers.

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: In the server's public root. It works fine without the second and third lines (i.e. the usual Codeigniter redirect).